# Leaving Small Company Without Having Added Value

Tags: job-offer, new-job, resignation

I have been at my current job in finance for just over 3 months and it has come in a bit under my expectations. Recently I received an offer from another company that I think I would enjoy more, with remote work (which is a plus for me) and a pay increase. If it was as easy as snapping my fingers and having the switch done, I would have already done it, but I have some concerns about leaving my current job.

The training period for my current job is 6 months - 1 year, so as of now I have not added any value and have been a large investment of time from the two owners (I am the second employee). My bosses have also been paying for my housing for the past 3 months and have a rent agreement for the next two months, they have had me over for dinner, etc. For some more background, I am 20 years old, this is my second 'real' job, and my bosses can be a bit intense, yelling at times, although I think that is something that comes with the culture of a wall street job?

Does anyone have any guidance on whether or not it would be appropriate to leave this job? I anticipate the conversation will be one of the hardest of my life, I would without a doubt be letting my bosses down very much, they interviewed several people for the position and finally decided on me and have invested 5 figures of $ and much more worth of their time in me, just for me to leave 3 months in and without having added any value. I dread the conversation so much that I cannot even decide if I should do it! But as I said, I know I *want* to take the new offer.

Note that if I were to stay a bit longer (to make my tenure a year at least, rather than 3 months), I would just be having taken more value from the company. The process to become productive takes a long time. I am not concerned with whether or not I'm able to use this tenure on my resume.

Apologies if the question is a bit personal for this board - but I'm wondering if in these cases it's considered very 'bad' to leave, or is it 'just business'?

Comment: "that comes with the culture of a wall street job?" Abuse is abuse. It doesn't matter if it's part of the wall street culture or not unless your intent is to enter another equally abusive wall street company. They control your housing. Make sure your exit strategy is well thought out. Read your contract. Read your housing contract also. Have a lawyer look at it if you need to. Be ready to be illegally evicted. Don't ask us for permission. These things are super awkward, but they happen all the time.

Comment: Think of it this way: do you think they prefer you tell them now after three months and $10000 or after 12 months and $40000?

Answer (score 5):

I think you know what you want and therefore what you have to do.

It's literally just business and if they invested 5 figures on you that is still is in probation period that's on them not you.

Fear and dread are totally normal, the best decisions are sometimes the hardest.

Answer (score 5):

Leaving a company is “just business” but make sure you fully understand the ramifications first as they absolutely will take it badly in this situation.

Review your employment contract, it’s very common to have “you have to pay it back if you leave soon” clauses for expensive training.  Also expect to be tossed out of the housing they are paying for with no notice if they have the lease on it.  Don’t count on them for any reference or similar in the future. Just assume they will do anything spiteful they can do and make sure to pre-plan to protect yourself accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Leaving the job is business as usual.  Business owners have to be prepared for people to leave, which is why there's a distinction between owners and employees.

Personally, I wouldn't look back as relates to this job.  You state that they went through a whole bunch of applicants, and they picked you in the end.  Have you ever considered that the other applicants might not have showed any tolerance for the intensity and yelling that you're putting up with now??? In other words, have you considered that your bosses might think you're young and gullible?  Give that a think or two.